# Retrieve rows with n oldest and n newest dates per group

Tags: python, pandas

Let's suppose that I have the following dataset in `python` and `pandas`:

```
Stock_id    Date    Stock_value
1   10/04/2019  2
1   11/04/2019  5
1   12/04/2019  1
1   13/04/2019  9
1   14/04/2019  6
1   15/04/2019  5
1   16/04/2019  7
2   12/04/2019  2
2   13/04/2019  9
2   14/04/2019  2
2   15/04/2019  4
2   16/04/2019  9
```

Now I want to have the n ( 2 in my specific example) rows with the oldest dates per group:

```
Stock_id    Date    Stock_value
1   10/04/2019  2
1   11/04/2019  5
2   12/04/2019  2
2   13/04/2019  9
```

Also separately I want to have the n (2 in my specific example) rows with the newest dates per group:

```
Stock_id    Date    Stock_value
1   15/04/2019  5
1   16/04/2019  7
2   15/04/2019  4
2   16/04/2019  9
```

How can I do each of these (separately) in `python` and `pandas`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) with [`GroupBy.tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html):

Also datetimes has to be sorted with `Stock_id`, so use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
df = df.sort_values(['Stock_id','Date'])

df1 = df.groupby('Stock_id').head(2)
print (df1)
   Stock_id       Date  Stock_value
0         1 2019-04-10            2
1         1 2019-04-11            5
7         2 2019-04-12            2
8         2 2019-04-13            9

df2 = df.groupby('Stock_id').tail(2)
print (df2)
    Stock_id       Date  Stock_value
5          1 2019-04-15            5
6          1 2019-04-16            7
10         2 2019-04-15            4
11         2 2019-04-16            9
```

Solution with `nsmallest` and `nlargest`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Stock_id', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(2, 'Date'))
print (df1)
   Stock_id       Date  Stock_value
0         1 2019-04-10            2
1         1 2019-04-11            5
7         2 2019-04-12            2
8         2 2019-04-13            9

df2 = df.groupby('Stock_id', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2, 'Date'))
print (df2)
    Stock_id       Date  Stock_value
6          1 2019-04-16            7
5          1 2019-04-15            5
11         2 2019-04-16            9
10         2 2019-04-15            4
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Actually I tested this but it did not work for me (it still returned all the dates); then I saw that I had an error at my source code and this is why it did not work haha.

Comment: By the way, what about using nlargest() and nsmallest()? If it works then you can skip the .sort_values part I guess?

Comment: @PoeteMaudit - ya, it is possible, but obviously much slowier.

Comment: Ok this sounds good. (by the way it is not that obvious to me but probably because I do not know how exactly these pandas functions work under the hood).